# How to know the adb commands supported by an APK?

Tags: android, apk, android-debug, adb

I am working in a company where some of my work includes some interactions with APK files. I just came across an APK file which was developed by some internal team and there is not much documentation for it.

I am wondering if there is any way to know the different commands available(API reference) for APK? Or is it always documentation from the provider sole source of information for any given APK?

OR even there is anyway to know more about the errors rather than running them in command prompt using adb commands?

I am sorry for the naive question but I am fairly new to android development.

Answer (score 0):

Didnt get your question clearly but if you searching for .apk command option 
so you can get this from this link.

https://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/wiki/ApktoolOptions

if your are new to android just go through this website you will get what you want and full knowledge of android application how they are build and their compilation

http://developer.android.com/training/index.html